# Is there a way I can have a separate background image for each button in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

In the website I am trying to create, I want a 7x7 table, each cell being a "button" that you can click on to toggle between images. Almost like a bingo board, you click on a cell and it will mark it as being completed by switching to another image. I am using localstorage to store which image is being shown so a user can keep their progress basically.

My problem is that since there is only 1 "backgroundImage" property, how do I have a different image in each box that I can toggle without affecting the others?

The javascript I provide is the same function twice, as it works for the first button but not for the second one, as I am guessing the background image is being conflicted with since they are both trying to access the same one.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js" data-semver="3.0.0" data-require="jquery"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

      <table>
          <tr>
              <th>T</th>
              <th>W</th>
              <th>I</th>
              <th>S</th>
              <th>T</th>
              <th>E</th>
              <th>D</th>
          </tr>
          
          <tr>
              <th><button class="button1"></button></th>
              <th><button class="button2"></button></th>
              <th>Task 3</th>
              <th>Task 4</th>
              <th>Task 5</th>
              <th>Task 6</th>
              <th>Task 7</th>
          </tr>
      </table>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
button
{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;       /* set to 100% */
   height: 100%;      /* set to 100% */
   margin-bottom: 0.5em;
   padding-top: .6em;
   padding-bottom: .6em;
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #aaabbb;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: solid #cccccc 1px;
   clear:right;
   float:right;
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
  
  if (localStorage.getItem('backgroundImage') !== null) {
        url = localStorage.backgroundImage;
        $('.button1').css('backgroundImage', url);
    }
    else
    {
      url = 'url(images/button1.png)';
    }
    
    
$('.button1').click(function(){
    if(url == "url(images/button1.png)"){
        localStorage.removeItem('backgroundImage');
        $('.button1').css('backgroundImage', 'url(images/button1no.png)');
        localStorage.setItem('backgroundImage', 'url(images/button1no.png)');
        }
    else {
        url = 'url(images/button1no.png)';
        localStorage.removeItem('backgroundImage');
        $('.button1').css('backgroundImage', 'url(images/button1.png)');
        localStorage.setItem('backgroundImage', 'url(images/button1.png)');
        }
    });
  
  
});

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

$(function(){
  
  if (localStorage.getItem('backgroundImage') !== null) {
        url = localStorage.backgroundImage;
        $('.button2').css('backgroundImage', url);
    }
    else
    {
      url = 'url(images/button2.png)';
    }
    
    
$('.button1').click(function(){
    if(url == "url(images/button2.png)"){
        localStorage.removeItem('backgroundImage');
        $('.button2').css('backgroundImage', 'url(images/button2no.png)');
        localStorage.setItem('backgroundImage', 'url(images/button2no.png)');
        }
    else {
        url = 'url(images/button2no.png)';
        localStorage.removeItem('backgroundImage');
        $('.button2').css('backgroundImage', 'url(images/button2.png)');
        localStorage.setItem('backgroundImage', 'url(images/button2.png)');
        }
    });
  
  
});
```

Comment: you are only storing state for 1 button. you need to store state of all buttons(either using unique keys, or just using an array and storing it serialized and then deserialize it onload) in order to handle this. you'll probably want to use a loop as well or you'll be writing a ton of copy paste code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store an array of the values instead of one value. Local Storage does not support complex values, but you can use JSON to encode it. So when you set the value, you would do something like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('backgroundImage', JSON.stringify(someArray));
```

And when you read it, parse it:

```
myArrayofValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('backgroundImage'))
```

Remember that by default the value will be empty, so you may want to set an initial value of an empty array first.

Comment: I see, I understand what you are getting at but I'm really new to localStorage and how to actually use it. Is there any way you could elaborate on where I would place this code or how the array I would need to make would look? Thanks a lot for the reply either way though!

Comment: Well to be fair, your question focused on how to store multiple values in LocalStorage where an array made sense. How to build the entire application would be out of scope for StackOverflow. I'd say _try_ the techniques I described, and see if you can come back with a firmer question?

Comment: Yeah, I got it with the answer you provided me earlier but didn't update the thread as solved. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions here:

1. How to toggle bettween two images for each buttons
2. How to store the "current" image for each button

I would use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store both images url AND the current one (and a number telling which one is used). That makes it easy to maintain all the urls directly in your markup.

I would also use it to store the "index" of each button, just to simplify the correspondance of each buttons with the index of an array to be stored in localStorage.

So on click, you will simply toggle between 2 urls and store the new "image number" in the array, at the right index.

Notice that it isn't the url that is stored... it's already in the markup.

Now, as @Raymond Camden explained, localStorage can store a string... Not an object or an array. That is why [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) are used.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // retrieve localStorage if exist
  let bg_numbers = [];
  /*if (localStorage.getItem("bg_numbers") !== null) {
    bg_numbers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bg_numbers"))
  }*/
  console.log(bg_numbers)

  // Setting the data-bg_current and data-btn_index
  $("button").each(function(index, btn) {
    let $btn = $(btn);

    // Get the urls for this button
    let backgrounds = [$btn.data("bg_1"), $btn.data("bg_2")];

    // Retreive the image number used, if any
    let currentImage = (bg_numbers[index] && bg_numbers[index] === 1) ? 1 : 0;
    // Set it
    $btn.css("background-image", `url('${backgrounds[currentImage]}')`);
    // Update the data attributes, since thos are zero on page load
    $btn.data("bg_current", currentImage);
    $btn.data("btn_index", index)
  });

  $("button").on("click", function() {
    let $btn = $(this);

    // Get the index of this button
    let index = $btn.data("btn_index")

    // Get the urls for this button
    let backgrounds = [$btn.data("bg_1"), $btn.data("bg_2")];

    // Toggle the image
    let currentImage = ($(this).data("bg_current") === 1) ? 0 : 1;
    $(this).css("background-image", `url('${backgrounds[currentImage]}')`);

    // Update the array and save to localStorage
    bg_numbers[index] = currentImage
    //localStorage.setItem("bg_numbers", JSON.stringify(bg_numbers))
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  /* set to 100% */
  height: 100%;
  /* set to 100% */
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-top: 0.6em;
  padding-bottom: 0.6em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #aaabbb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid #cccccc 1px;
  clear: right;
  float: right;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>T</th>
    <th>W</th>
    <th>I</th>
    <th>S</th>
    <th>T</th>
    <th>E</th>
    <th>D</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th><button data-bg_1="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.png?text=Button 1" data-bg_2="https://loremflickr.com/150/150" data-bg_current=0 data-btn_index=0></button></th>
    <th><button data-bg_1="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.png?text=Button 2" data-bg_2="https://loremflickr.com/150/150" data-bg_current=0></button></th>
    <th>Task 3</th>
    <th>Task 4</th>
    <th>Task 5</th>
    <th>Task 6</th>
    <th>Task 7</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I commented all lines related to localStorage here since SO snippet are disallowing it... And it was throwing an ugly error. But see my [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/poEVypo?editors=1111).